# Почему object-fit не работает с <picture> <source>?

Tags: html, css, css3

У меня есть изображения, которые в зависимости от ширины экрана меняться на изображения более высокого разрешения.

html:

```
<div class="movie">
    <picture>
     <source srcset="src/img/posters/poster-4-big.jpg" media="(min-width: 2000px)">
     <img src="src/img/posters/poster4.png" alt="Инферно">
    </picture>
</div>
```

css:

```
.movie picture img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Когда ширина окна до 2000px - изображения кладутся в контейнер как надо - картинка на всю ширину и высоту без искажений, однако, при ширине свыше 2000px картинка помещается только по ширине родительского блока, тем самым оставляя отступы снизу, я делаю вывод, что object-cover не работает, что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как указано в документации [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-3/#propdef-object-fit), `object-fit` применим к `replaced elements`.

Такими элементами являются теги `audio`, `canvas`, `embed`, `iframe`, `img`, `input`, `object`, и `video`. [список](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements)

Вам нужно стили задавать для `img` так как picture - это контейнер

```css
.movie img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Если у вас верно указаны размеры контейнера для .movie то все будет работать

**Дополнено о теге picture:**

> Элемент picture не рендерит никакой контент, а лишь является справочным контейнером для вложенного в него тега img.
> Поэтому для большинства задач хватит сокращенной записи, совсем без использования picture:

```html
<img src="image.jpg" alt="My image" 
    [srcset="<список URL с дескрипторами>"] 
    [sizes="<ваши размеры в зависимости от раскладки>"]>
```

[источник ХАБР](https://habr.com/ru/post/237991/)

**UPD**

> Благодарю за ответ, однако, убрав picture ничего не поменялось. Насчет второго способа - пробую, но почему-то подгружает только в самом большом разрешении, надо поэксперементировать

Посмотрите на пример при разных разрешениях:
Убирать picture не нужно, этому тегу не нужно css задавать.

Работает ли у Вас нижеприведённый код?
Я поменял на 1024px+ - одна картинка, 500- - другая картина - остальные - картинка по умолчанию

```css
.movie {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.movie img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="movie">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/00aad4/fff&text=1024+" media="(min-width: 1024px)"><source srcset="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/12d400/fff&text=mobile" media="(max-width: 500px)">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=default" alt="Инферно">
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, однако, убрав picture ничего не поменялось. Насчет второго способа - пробую, но почему-то подгружает только в самом большом разрешении, надо поэксперементировать

Comment: @BERTOLDO обновил, посмотрите после строки **UPD** сниппет, запустите и посмотрите при разных разрешениях. Такое ли вы поведение ожидали?

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, скорее всего не хватает информации о родительском элементе для .movie чтоб понять почему в вашем случае так происходит, как видите по вашему коду в сниппете все работает именно так как вы хотели (cover работает верно), попробуйте воспроизвести ошибку в сниппете

Comment: Спасибо  за ответ, ошибка заключалась в том, что тег picture был не на весь родительский контейнер, поэтому и изображение "съезжало", поставив picture на weight: 100% и height: 100% все стало работать как надо.

Comment: @bertoldo ошибка не в этом была, тегу picture не нужно указывать никаких свойств, это контейнер, это тоже самое что указать тегу head display:block и отобразить на странице

Comment: Может, это поведение было вызвано какими-то внешними факторами. Но именно этим способом я решил проблему.

Comment: В любом случае, информация, которую вы дали может быть полезна тем, кто столкнулся с похожей проблемой, но мое решение не подошло. Спасибо за участие!

Comment: @BERTOLDO проверьте, скорее всего вы указали для тега picture или свойство display или позиционирование, у picture должно быть 0 стилей (ни одного вообще), ни позиционирование ни display, из-за этого, скорее всего, он и видим и учитывается в браузере. После удаления этих свойств все станет на свои места, как и должно быть.

Comment: в том-то и дело, что не указывал, странное поведение